# How to Remove the White Separator in Cell?

Tags: ios, uitableview

[image]

This is what I am doing.

`UITableViewControlller` in that I am loading Container View as Static Cell, and those containers are embedded to a tableview controller.

I have made all views  background color to black still the separator is coming white at starting of a cell

Comment: Set `seperator` property of `tableView` to `None` by `[self.tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone]`.

Comment: can you please show your code? so i can identify the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the table's `separatorInset`.

```
self.tableView.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Click on your TableView->go to Attribute Inspector->Separator Insets->Choose Custom and set up Left = 0;

Answer (score 1):

it is very simple just set your cell separator edge inset to zero

```
[tblViewLoadReq setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];
}
```